# Can't start ionic app

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework, mobile

After upgrading node and npm I can't start an old ionic app, here is the error:

```
± |master U:1 ?:1 ✗| → ionic serve

> ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve /Users/John/Dropbox/www/salon-app
> ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"

sh: ionic-app-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/John/.npm/_logs/2018-06-16T15_54_50_743Z-debug.log
There was an error serving your Ionic application: There was an error with the spawned command: serve
```

Info

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.2.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS
Node Version: v10.4.1
Xcode version: Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000
```

I have tried removing `node_modules` and `npm install` but with no luck.

//LE after running `npm audit` it shows problems with some packages, I'm trying to update those

Comment: Seems like there were some breaking changes ...

Answer (score 1):

After removing `node_modules` and reinstalling ionic `npm install -g cordova ionic` and running `npm audit` to see what packages are broken it works again.

I don't know exactly what fixed but I have repeated this process and it worked.